# Can't get UITableViewAutomaticDimension to work properly

Tags: swift2, snapkit

I have a fairly standard UITableView that populates via custom cell. That cell is simply an image and a label at the moment. I cannot, for the life of me, get it to resize on it's own.

When I include UITableViewAutomaticDimension, I lose the ability to populate my data in addition to incorrect layouts.

Without UITableViewAutomaticDimension, the data is displayed properly.

I **am** using [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) to handle constraints and Meteor/[SwiftDDP](https://github.com/siegesmund/SwiftDDP) to handle the data, but there is another UITableView in the project that seems to be working properly

**ViewController**

```
class CommentViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var commentTable:UITableView!
    var comments:MeteorCollection<Comment>!

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        comments = MeteorCollection<Comment>(name: "comments")

        createView()

        Meteor.subscribe("postsComments", params: [["postId": self.source!.id!]]) {}
    }

    func createView() {
        let contentTableView = UITableView(frame: content.frame)
        content.addSubview(contentTableView)
        contentTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.commentTable = contentTableView
        contentTableView.delegate = self
        contentTableView.dataSource = self

        contentTableView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
          make.top.equalTo(content)
          make.left.equalTo(content)
          make.right.equalTo(content)
          make.height.equalTo(content).inset(65)
        }

        contentTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        contentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 350

    }
}
```

**CommentTableViewDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

extension CommentViewController {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.comments.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CommentTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        if let card = cell as? CommentTableViewCell {
            let item = self.comments.sorted[indexPath.row]
            card.populate(item)
        }

        return CommentTableViewCell()
    }

    func reloadTableView() {
        self.commentTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

An example of my garbled mess when **not** using UITableViewAutomaticDimension
[image]

An example of my garbled mess when using UITableViewAutomaticDimension
[image]

Comment: please set contentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1 //estimate value if less then work properly

Answer (score 4):

It might be due to improper constraint within cell. Please add constraint properly in table view cell and set these two properties of UILable from Attributes inspector section of storyboard:

- lines to 0
- Line break to word wrap

or you can also set these properties from code:

```
 self.lblxyz.numberOfLines = 0
 self.lblxyz.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Note - Do not fix the height of UILable.

Hope it will help you... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works but, I've been through the same problem recently, and i fixed it by changing the `estimatedRowHeight` .

Can you please try once with:-

```
contentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 350
```

to, `contentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160`

Comment: This didn't do the trick. Where are you putting your estimatedRowHeight lines at? Perhaps they are different than mine.

Comment: are you sure about the constraints? 
yeah, i've been using this function by creating a outlet of **tableview** and 
`tableview.estimatedRowHeight` while viewDidAppear.